Does using a for loop with model.fit give the same results as not using it?
Following codes yield the same result?
#code1
 model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=300, batch_size = 128, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

#code2
epochs = 300
for j in range(epochs):
    for i in range(len(train_x) // batch_size):
        model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, epochs=1, batch_size = batch_size, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

The two codes will operate in the same manner or not.

Why don't you just run them and try?

Hi@user24640442,While both the pieces of code seek to train the model for the same number of epochs, the processes they initiate will not be the same. As stated above, Code 1 is the most preferable method when training models using the Keras. It makes use of the built-in optimization for training and validation, manage epochs and batch with ease, and is more efficient and easy to train compared to the other methods.

Code 2 should be used for training because it is cumbersome when it comes to epochs and validation and it also involves unnecessary repetitions that slows down performance and time. If you require the training loops as per the specifications, then it is possible to use TensorFlow’s tf. also recommend using GradientTape for greater control, however, for most of the cases, it is desirable to stay within the model. fit is advisable.
